# MSBuild - how to create "critical section"

Tags: msbuild, mutex

I have a parallel build of multiple projects, each one of those at some point in time does invoke `<Exec />` task. This exec task is running 3pty tool that crashes if there is another instance of this tool running. Is there some native way how to implement "mutex" in msbuild ?

The obvious solution (that works) is to make the build synchronous - but that is slowing down the whole build.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I ended up writing my own msbuild extension library like below

msbuild part:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MutexExec" AssemblyFile="$(CommonTasksAssembly)" />
```

C# part:

```
// <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="16.9.0" />
// <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" Version="16.9.0" />
// <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="16.9.0" />

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Like a Exec task, but with critical section
/// </summary>
public class MutexExec : Exec
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets mutex name
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string MutexName { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (stopwatch.Elapsed < timeout)
        {
            bool createdNew;
            using (var mutex = new Mutex(true, this.MutexName, out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew)
                {
                    bool result = base.Execute();
                    try
                    {
                        this.Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Normal, "Releasing {0}", this.MutexName);
                        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        this.Log.LogError("Failure releasing {0} - {1}", this.MutexName, e);
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }

            this.Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Normal, "Waiting for {0} - ellapsed {1}", this.MutexName, stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            continue;
        }

        this.Log.LogError("Failed to acquire {0} in {1}.", this.MutexName, timeout);
        return false;
    }
}
```